# How to write a test suite for appium automation for android

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

I am automating my android app using Appium (Java).
I have written individual classes for the test cases (around 20/30 cases).
Now I have to demonstrate the automation - one way is to run each of the cases individually. I want it execute each one of them one by one. Is there any approach for writing suite or abstracting the cases?
Any suggestion / approach to proceed or any example / guidelines to acheive that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a TestNG suite, and run from there.

Create a `TestNG.xml` file in your project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suite name="Suite">
        <test name="Tests">
            <classes>
                <class name="PackageName.ClassName"/>
                <class name="PackageName.ClassName"/>
                <class name="PackageName.ClassName"/>
                <class name="PackageName.ClassName"/>
                <class name="PackageName.ClassName"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

Additionally you can setup the order they execute using [priorities](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#priority()).

Hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: thanks that gave me a good idea. just one more thing - > It is a simple xml file? and I can run it directly from my Eclipse? Thanks

Comment: yes! It's just an xml file and right clicking on it in eclipse or intelliJ will give the option to "Run as a TestNG suite"

Comment: @LiamFerris : Can i run all Classes for the same project together? For example 10 classes each one contain 20 methods ?
--> Method are ordred by priority 
--> Classes are ordred by priority also ?

Comment: @Emna Yes! Read up on priority documentation.You could either prioritize methods "1-20" in the class you want to prioritize first, then "21-40" in the second class and so on. Or alternatively use the testNG tag `<test>` and include one class in each, and have them run one by one. Hope this helps

Comment: @LiamFerris you mean finally i run only one class in which test priority is 1 for example and all my methods in all classes will run one by one ?